# VS Code extension development error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I'm currently learning how to develop an extension for VSCode.  I've been following tons of examples and tutorials.  I think I almost have it but I keep getting this error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()

The resource it is trying to load is my compiled main.js.

As I am new to working with VS Code extensions I'm not 100% sure what al lis needed to help with debugging this but I'll include what I think is right.

So first from the panel that is being created I know you have to enable scripts and include resources may come from.  I did that here:

```js
// Otherwise, create a new panel.
    const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
      TexAboutPanel.viewType,
      "HelloWorld",
      column || vscode.ViewColumn.One,
      {
        // Enable javascript in the webview
        enableScripts: true,

        // And restrict the webview to only loading content from our extension's `media` directory.
        localResourceRoots: [
          vscode.Uri.joinPath(extensionUri, "media"),
          vscode.Uri.joinPath(extensionUri, "build"),
        ],
      }
    )
```

my build folder looks like this:
[image: Build file structure]

The main example I am using to go by structures just like this and that one works.  So I'm not sure what I am missing or what else to try?